# How do I modify Wordpress WP_Query with a custom field value after filtering?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have three select boxes that allow a list of custom posts to be filtered, any or all of the options can be selected and then a "Filter" button is clicked which then reloads the page and appends the filtered variable(s) to the URL as a query string. This works perfectly fine with the two custom taxonomies I have:

```
$categories = array('company-sector', 'company-location');
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    if (isset($_GET[$category]) && !empty($_GET[$category])) {
        $query['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy'  => $category,
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => $_GET[$category]
        );
    }
}
```

However, using the same logic on the third filter (a custom field created with ACF), the list of posts do not change:

```
if (isset($_GET['company-status']) && !empty($_GET['company-status'])) {
    $query['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key' => 'company_status',
        'value' => $_GET['company-status'],
    );
}
```

This meta query works just fine if I manually add it into the initial WP_Query like so:

```
$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'company-post',
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'company_status',
            'value' => 'acquired'
        )
    )
);
```

However, attempting to add it into the initial query after getting the variable from the query string doesn't seem to work, what am I doing wrong here?

//edit

Even this is working:

```
$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'company-post',
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'company_status',
            'value' => $_GET['company-status']
        )
    )
);
```

So it has to be something to do with how I'm appending the meta_query to the initial WP_Query...

Comment: if your var_dump($_GET['company-status']) are you getting your expected results?

Comment: Haven't tried var_dump(), but echo $_GET['company-status']; returns what I'm expecting to see.

Comment: var_dump() is returning: string(7) "current". ('current' or 'acquired' are the two options at present, which appear in the back end as ACF radio buttons.)

Comment: I've updated my question with some more information relating to this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you could use pre_get_posts for this in your functions.php

```
// Load our function when hook is set
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'js-modifying-main-query' );

function js-modifying-main-query( $query ) {
    $status = $_GET['company-status'];
    if($status && $status != ""){

        if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'company-post' ) {

            $query->set('meta_key', 'company_status');
            $query->set('meta_value', $status);

        }

    }
}
```

Haven't tested it - just an initial thought.

//EDIT

To see your query variables, you can use this :

```
global $wp_query;
var_dump($wp_query->query_vars);
```

Comment: If nothing else - this should get you on the right track.

Comment: Had to change the '-' to '_' when declaring the function to get it to run and even then I get: Undefined index: post_type

Comment: hmm - you can var dump your query vars, to see what is present in it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure why my initial code isn't working, but I've managed to come up with a workaround that seems to do what I need it to:

```
$status = false;
if (isset($_GET['company-status']) && !empty($_GET['company-status'])) {
    $status = array(
        'key' => 'company_status',
        'value' => $_GET['company-status'],
    );
}

$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'company-post',
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array($status)
);
```

//edit

Even this is working:

```
$status = false;
if (isset($_GET['company-status']) && !empty($_GET['company-status'])) {
    $status[] = array(
        'key' => 'company_status',
        'value' => $_GET['company-status'],
    );
}

$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'company-post',
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => $status
);
```

But as soon as I try this, it fails:

```
if (isset($_GET['company-status']) && !empty($_GET['company-status'])) {
    $query['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key' => 'company_status',
        'value' => $_GET['company-status'],
    );
}

$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'company-post',
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You push the wrong value for `company-status`.

```
if (isset($_GET['company-status']) && !empty($_GET['company-status'])) {
    $query['meta_query'][] = array(
        array(
            'key' => 'company_status',
            'value' => $_GET['company-status'],
        )
    );
}
```

... makes this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => company_sector
            [value] => val1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => company_status
            [value] => val2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => company_status
                    [value] => val3
                )

        )

)
```

You should push to `meta_query` array this way:

```
$query['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key' => 'company_status',
    'value' => $_GET['company-status'],
);
```

Also, if parameter `relation` is ommited, query would check for all the keys and values - but I assume you know this.

Comment: I've already tried both ways, I forgot to mention this in my initial question. I've updated my question to reflect this. I've also updated my answer with some further testing, based on what you've suggested, and it still doesn't seem to work.

Also, if `relation` is required, then does that not change how I push to meta_query?

Comment: Please post `print_r` of your `$query` variable, I think that's where the problem will be.